# Connect to xampp database from internet

Tags: mysql, xampp, xubuntu

I have a website hosted on my university's account space and on 000webhost and a database on my home pc (xubuntu OS) using Xampp.

I need the website to query the xampp database to get some data but I can only manage to query the database locally (using the 192.168.x.x ip address).

How can I setup xampp to accept connections to the database from the internet?

I found random solutions from other posts like configuring config files in /lampp/etc but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Where did you stack? Did you reload server?

Comment: Yeah. I did everything. Changed configurations and stuff with no effect. I have now set a static IP address to my pc but is a 192.168.x.x (that is local right?). From my LAN i can access my server, but how can you access it from the internet (e.g your pc)?

Answer (score 0):

If your are able to access XAMPP DB using IP other than localhost, your XAMPP configuration is good. Guess its not a static IP, the 192.168.X.X ip could be a proxy ip assigned by your router locally. You need a static IP address to achieve this.

For experimentation purpose, you can try port forwarding (ill-advised) and use your actual IP to access your DB. This would be transient till you restart your router or till IP reset period config in your router.

Comment: So, i set a static ip for my server pc and forwarded ports 80 and 22. The static ip the router gives me through DHCP is 192.168.10.33. How can someone from another network see this ip? Isn't it only for my lan?

Comment: Static IP should be provided by the network provider..
192.168.10.33 which u have set through DHCP is fixed "PROXY IP" not the actual IP. Check myipaddress.com to know your actual IP.
1. [Dynamic IP & Static IP](http://searchwindevelopment.techtarget.com/definition/static-IP-address-dynamic-IP-address)
2. [Hosting with Dynamic IP](http://superuser.com/questions/20580/how-can-a-computer-with-dynamic-ip-work-as-a-webserver)